# what are the effects of a check "is null" on a where clause parameter?

Tags: sql, jpa

I'm extending a jpa query and have found the following where clause condition :

```
(lower(projectent2_.proj_id) like lower(?) or ? is null)
```

Apart from other mistakes (proj_id is number and is a pk so it can't be null and it's useless to lower and like it) , i was wandering what are the effects of "?  is null" on the query . I'm a bit surprised jpa doesn't complain i'm applying a is null condition to a parameter rather than a column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not provide a parameter value (meaning it is `null`) then the query will result all records. That is a common use case.

Like that you can remove the comparison with `projectent2_.proj_id` in your query on demand.